# minimal $KC$-topological space

Tags: general-topology

If $P$ is a topological property, then a space $(X, \tau)$ is said to be minimal $P$ (respectively, maximal) if $(X, \tau)$ has property $P$ but no topology on $X$ which is strictly smaller (respectively, strictly larger ) than $\tau$ has $P$.

The  spaces are called **$KC$-spaces** in which every  compact subset is closed.

**I know that every minimal $KC$-topological space  is compact.**

> Is  every minimal $KC$-topological space, maximal compact?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is true. We will prove a stronger result:

> $$KC+\text{compact}\Longrightarrow \text{maximal compact}$$

proof: let $(X,\tau)$ be a compact KC-topology. Assume it's not maximal compact, i.e. there exists a compact topology $\tau'$ on X such that $\tau'$ is strictly finer than $\tau$. Then there exists a $\tau'$-closed set $A$ which is not $\tau$-closed. Since $(X,\tau')$ is compact, $A$ is $\tau'$-compact. A compact set in a finer topology is also compact in a coarser topology. Hence $A$ is $\tau$-compact. As $(X,\tau)$ is KC, $A$ is $\tau$-closed, contrary to the choice of $A$. Hence the result follows.

Since you already knew that every minimal KC space is compact (a proof can be found [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/466000/every-minimal-kc-space-is-compact)), we are done.

---

The converse of the result in the quote box also holds.