# Is there non-compacted Hausdorff Space?

Tags: general-topology, topological-groups

If P is a topological property, then a space $(X, \tau)$ is said to be **minimal $P$** (respectively, maximal) if $(X, \tau)$ has property $P$ but no topology on $X$ which is strictly smaller (respectively, strictly larger ) than τ has P.

A topological space is called **KC space** if every compact subset is closed.

**Theorem:**

1: Every minimal $KC$-topological space is compact.

2:Every maximal compact space is minimal $KC$ space.

3:Every Hausdorff space is $KC$ space.

> **Is every minimal $KC$-topological, maximal compact?**
>
> **Is there non-compacted Hausdorff Space ?**
>
> **Is there a Compact  Space not to be Hausdorff?**

Comment: What does "compacted" mean?

Comment: 2) $\mathbb R$ is Hausdorff but not compact.  3) The Sierpiński space is compact but not Hausdorff.

Comment: 1 is answered [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3200538/minimal-kc-topological-space). Please don't post the same question twice.

Comment: Any finite space is compact, whether or not it is Hausdorff... $\Bbb R$  with the usual topology is Hausdorff but not compact.... If $X$ is a compact Hausdorff space then any strictly stronger topology on $X$ (if there is one) is Hausdorff but not compact.... I have not studied your 1st Q

Answer (score 1):

Any cofinite topology on an infinite set (like $\mathbb{N}$) is not Hausdorff (but $T_1$) and compact. The one-point compactification (aka Aleksandrov extension) of $\mathbb{Q}$ is KC, compact but not Hausdorff as well.

A reference to your first claim is [here](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0166864108001417).

Do you have a reference for the second one too? The last one is classical.

A minimal KC space is compact, as we saw, and a KC compact space is maximal compact. So that answers your first question.

Comment: Yes. KC+compact $\Rightarrow$ maximal compact and minimal KC $\Rightarrow$ KC+compact. Again, this question has already been [asked](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3200538/minimal-kc-topological-space)

Comment: @YuiToCheng That's not the same as maximal compact $\implies$ minimal KC, is it?

Comment: No, it's not the same. But the OP is asking whether minimal KC $\Rightarrow$ maximal compact.

Comment: It is quite easy to see that a KC compact space is both maximal compact and minimal KC. It is also quite easy to show that every maximal compact space is KC. The remaining implication that every minimal KC space is compact is the most difficult one and was proved relatively recently.

Comment: @user87690 For the record, minimal KC $\Rightarrow$ compact is proved [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/466000/every-minimal-kc-space-is-compact)

Comment: @YuiToCheng That’s the proof from the paper I quoted.

Answer (score 0):

An example of non-Hausdorff compact space is a compact neighborhood of the origins in the line with two origins. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-Hausdorff_manifold